# Strange Alphanumeric folders in my D drive

Tags: windows-8

I am seeing strange folders with long hash like alpha numeric names on my d drive (secondary partition). I have experienced a few of these a few years ago on xp ( I use linux mostly nowadays), and that was office updates n such, and it was 1-3 folders. Now it is closer to 8-9 folders, no MS office on this machine and its but a few months old, maybe a touch more than half a year.

The folders require admin access to go in if it helps. I want to know whats creating them, can I delete them, and how to ensure they dont pop up again.

Comment: some of them are created by a vc++ runtime update

Answer (score 1):

Can be from any number of (usually) MSFT apps that unpack before installing.  Sometimes they get orphaned during the install process due to unclean exit.

Either way I usually delete them immediately after install (if/when they occur) as re-running the original.exe recreates them anyways.

Dumb question, any of those folders identical size / file count.

Comment: netfx offline installer usually does it to me.

Comment: They sometimes come with a lot of `eula.xxxx.txt` files in drive root, also some INIs, EXE installer, `install.res.xxxx.dll`, `VC_RED.cab`, `VC.RED.MSI` and `vcredist.bmp`, all of these are safe to delete.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure why I never checked that.. All of them seem empty, even with hidden files shown.. I deleted them all, maybe Ill wait and see what caused them.. I think I tried to update to 8.1 and similar stuff recently..